# floating point division of many goods

Tags: python, c++, floating-point, cython

I have an amount of a resource 'stock'. I have customers that demand this stock. 
the stock is distributed amongst them. But because of floating point arithmetic, 
the sum of the quota each agent gets is sometimes a little higher than the stock.

```
for i in range(10000):
    nominal_demand = normalized_random(4)
    stock = random.random() * 10
    price = sum(nominal_demand) /  stock
    quota = nominal_demand / price
    assert sum(quota) <= stock, (stock, nominal_demand)
```

1. How do I solve this problem in pretty fashion?
2. How can I solve this in the assert statement, ignoring the 'little to much'?
3. How can I solve this in the assert statement, when the number of clients (the 4) is not known. (I know it is in the example but in the actual production code it's not.
4. I am also interested in C++ and cython solutions

Comment: The last customer standing usually gets all that is left.

Comment: Why do you tag this question [tag:c++]? I can't see any relevance. That you're interested in c++ cython solutions doesn't make these tags valid. Also your question is off-topic as _too broad_ anyway.

Comment: The problem is exactly the same in C++, I am interested in C++ solutions as well, see edit

Comment: Use a data type that has no rounding issues (such as decimal.Decimal)

Comment: Schore, thanks that generally is a good solution. But for performance issues and the fact that to much of the code base would have to be modified, not an option in the production code .

Comment: Well in that case you could hack in some arbitrary threshold (like 10**-10) and check that sum(quota) - stock <= threshold

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to use floating point, I don’t think there’s a “pretty solution”.  There will always be potential roundoff error.  SergeyA's answer of assigning the remainder to a customer sounds nice but is not reliable since floating point math is not commutative.
2. Define and use a method to test for approximate equality.  This [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0485/) and [this example implementation](https://github.com/PythonCHB/close_pep/blob/master/is_close.py) may be useful.
   `assert isclose(sum(quota), stock)`
3. Not sure I understand the concern here but this approach should generalize to n clients.  The error will scale with the magnitude of the stock but if you use relative tolerances, the tolerance should scale along with it.
4. Same approach applies to C++.